# Non-rectangular meshgrids in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization, mesh

I want to create a non-rectangular meshgrid in matlab.

Basically I have a polygon shaped feasible set I need to make a grid of in order to interpolate 3D data points in this set. The function for interpolation is given and requires finite (x, y, z) inputs. Where x is nx1, y is 1xm and z is nxm. Right now I have the mesh set up with linspace and set all NaN (infeasible) values to 0 before using my function, which is wrong of course (third figure).

Is there a simple solution for this?

I added a picture illustrating what I'm currently doing: First plot is the feasible set, second plot are solved sample data points in this set and third plot is the interpolation (currently still with rectangular meshgrid and NaN = 0). What I need is a meshgrid looking like the first figure (red polygon) instead of a rectangular one. In the third plot you can see that the rectangular meshgrid in combination with setting NaN to 0 (=infeasible values, not included in the red polygon set) results in a wrong interpolation along the edges, because it includes infeasible regions.

[image]

Here is my code using a rectangular meshgrid:

```
figure (2) %sample data
plot3(X0(1,:), X0(2,:), U, 'x')
%X0(1,:) and X0(2,:) are vectors corresponding to the Z-Values (blue sample data)
%X0 and U are in the feasible set (red polygon)

xv = linspace(xLb(1), xUb(1), 100);
yv = linspace(xLb(2), xUb(2), 100); %xLb and xUb are upper and lower bounds for the rectangle mesh
[x1,x2] = meshgrid(xv, yv);
Z = griddata(X0(1,:), X0(2,:), U, x1, x2);
%This grid obviously includes values that are not in the feasible set (red polygon) by its rectangular nature

Z(isnan(Z))=0; %set infeasible values to 0, wrong of course
testMPC = someInterpolationFunction([0:length(Z)-1]',[0:length(Z)-1],Z);
testMPC.showInterpolation(20,20) 
%this shows figure 3 in the attached picture
```

Comment: I don't know _polygonal feasible set_. But here it is required to provide a minimal working example i.e. an input and the expected output to help us understand the question and what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have addded a picture that illustrates what im trying to do. The first plot shows the feasible set, the second plot shows solved sample data points in the set and the third plot is what I actually need, just with a different mesh grid. As you can see in the third plot all results that are infeasible using a rectangular grid (dont appear in first red plot) and give NaN are set to 0. I need to avoid having infeasible data in my grid, thats why I would like to set up a mesh grid looking like my feasible set (first red plot)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
nRows = 100;
nCols = 200;

x1 = @(x) max(0, x-50);
x2 = @(x) min(nCols, nCols - 50 + x);

RR = zeros(nRows, nCols);
CC = zeros(nRows, nCols);

for iRow = 1:nRows
  c1 = x1(iRow);
  c2 = x2(iRow);
  
  colVec = linspace(c1, c2, nCols);
  
  RR(iRow, :) = iRow;
  CC(iRow, :) = colVec;
end

mesh(RR, CC, zeros(size(RR)))
```

[image]

You'd need to redefine the functions for `x1` and `x2` or course as well as the scaling, but this should give you an idea of how to get started.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just realised though that a polygon meshgrid is probably not the answer to my problem. My interpolation function requires Z to be a nxn matrix, this is automatically achieved with a rectangular meshgrid, a polygonal grid filled with values wouldn’t be quadratic though. I need to find some other solution to my problem.